# Move specific folders to a new location and leave a symlink at the old location to the new folder

Tags: shell, find, cp, mv

I have a lot of folders named `Archive.folder` in `/var/CommuniGate/Accounts/*/`. How can I move them to a new location and leave a symlink at the old folder to the new location?

Maybe use find and cp to move them?

```sh
find /var/CommuniGate/Accounts/ -name 'Archive.folder' -exec cp -r --parents {} . \;
```

This works fine for moving them and keeping the folder structure. But how can leave a link at the same time with ln? Also the link should replace the old folder.

I've tried executing the following after, it works if there is only one folder.

```sh
find /var/CommuniGate/Accounts/ -name 'Archive.folder' -delete

find * -name 'Archive.folder' | xargs -0 -iDIR sh -c 'mkdir -p /$(dirname DIR); ln -s -t /$(dirname DIR) $PWD/DIR'
```

I get `permission denied` for the `sh -c` for everything after the first directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can juste move your file to the desired location and then create the symlink :

- `mv /var/CommuniGate/Accounts/Archive.folder* new_location/`
- `ln -s new_location/Archive.folder* .`

Comment: I know. But Accounts has a lot of subfolders which each contain an Archive.folder.

Comment: Okay I see, then you can reuse your find command after in your new location

Comment: Do I need to delete the folders before?